# iOS, Xcode: how to embed framework but not link it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I am implementing some custom frameworks within the app and one of the requirements is to "**embed it but do not link**".
How can I do that?

I added framework with + in ***Target > Embedded binaries*** but it automatically appeared in Linked Frameworks and Libraries below.

Now when I run the app - I have a crash. I read some topics and got that the crash is because of my frameworks located in Linked Frameworks.

I am using workspace, pods. That framework is https://github.com/holzschu/ios_system/tree/8b33137d830c041482bf86cec5cf06d4d1aa19d4

Instruction:

```
 Integration with your app:
 Link your application with the ios_system.framework framework.
 Embed (but don't link) the frameworks corresponding to the commands you need (libtar.dylib if you need tar, libfiles.dylib for cp, rm, mv...).
 Add the two dictionaries, Resources/commandDictionary.plist and Resources/extraCommandsDictionary.plist to the "Copy Bundle Resources" step in your Xcode project.
```

I downloaded files to project by script. Added location of frameworks to Target> Build Settings > Framework search paths

Comment: Seems like an odd requirement, but I just (1) created a new project, (2) added a new target of framework type, then (3) saw it was *both* embedded and linked and (4) removed it from being linked. Result? The framework is embedded but not linked. Have you tried that?